# How to rename build name with assembly version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, azure-devops

Pls see screenshot.  I have setup continuos integration with tfsservice.
It builds and deploys after each checkin.

I would like to append or pre-pend if that word exists, the assembly version so that I can easy recognize what build generated what version, and I can easy identify in which build a bug appeared.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you need to get the version number from a library during the build, then you can use the [Assembly](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.6.0/html/2610c1b7-348a-901e-3c90-84a3deb99c38.htm) class in the MSBuild Extensions Pack to get the version number from the desired library.

Comment: its tfs service on the cloud, how can I edit the azure build definition?

Comment: Looks like TFService has its own workflow that does the build. Here is series of blogs by @EwaldHofman to get you started: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx

Comment: can I add a custom activity to tfs build on the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

This is feasible, but you need to customize your build template. 
A good starting point is the Visual Studio ALM Rangers' [BRDLite Reference Templates](http://vsarbrdlite.codeplex.com/). See **Assembly Versioning** example in the **BRDLite.Asp.NetTemplate.2012.2.xaml** template.

[image: BRDLite Assembly Versioning]